# Adding the value in database with html inside echo field in phpv

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add value of product_id inside database using bidupdate.php. 
But everytime i try this. It says Error in connection as explained in die function in php. The value of product_id is not passing. I think there is some error in the value phase. Please check it.

```
    <?php 
     if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
       echo '<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="bidupdate.php">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "<?php echo '.$_REQUEST['product_id'].'">';
       echo '<button input="submit" name="bid">Bid Now</button>';
       echo '</form>';
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: You check `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){` ... but then try using `$_REQUEST['product_id']` instead? However the code you provided really doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question or the mysterious error you say you get. Please provide relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call the value in php close within php. that is possible with html. Use this code

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
   echo '<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="bidupdate.php">';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "'.$_REQUEST['product_id'].'">';
   echo '<button input="submit" name="bid">Bid Now</button>';
   echo '</form>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Wrong:

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "<?php echo '.$_REQUEST['product_id'].'">';
```

You cannot use `<?php ?>` inside PHP code.

Corrected code:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "'.$_REQUEST['product_id'].'">';
```